# Netbeans - button function illegal start of expression

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I created a JFrame form and put a button on it, then created an actionformed inside source.  Program gives an error like **illegal start expression**

```
 private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    System.exit(0);
}
```

By the way, 
Before creating an actionformed for button, main function had the same error. When I created actionformed for button, it disappeared and program showed that error in button function.

Here is my main function

```
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
        Login dialog = new Login(new javax.swing.JFrame(), true); 
        dialog.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {

            @Override
           public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent e) {
               System.exit(0);
           } 
        });
        dialog.setVisible(true);

    });
}
```

Comment: `put a button on it, then created an actionformed inside source` Do you mean you added an ActionListener to the JButton? Please indicate where error occurs in code posted.

Comment: @copeg  
l added actionPerformed to the JButton. and then program created JButton function which is " private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)  ".
on that function(Button function)  illegal start of expression error occurs
  [link](http://i62.tinypic.com/2ns01o8.jpg)

Comment: Pictures are not the best way to diagnose issues with code - please edit your question to include the necessary code to reproduce.

Comment: Your code does not compile and does not include any button.

Comment: Well, l have solved the problem. l forgot to add "}" for the first public class